# I receive ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string when I am parsing an XML file

Tags: xml, plsql, xml-parsing

I have a table which contains an XMLTYPE column.
Into the XMLTYPE column, I have an XML document.

Here is the XML file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeliveryNotificationFile Sender="1234567891234" Receiver="1234567891234" FileID="EAI_2e105455-0251-77aa-e053-0eba1a0a9787" CreateDate="1900-01-01T01:01:01+01:00" SendDate="1900-01-01T01:01:01+01:00" MessageType="DELIVERY_STATUS">
  <DeliveryNotificationRecord>
    <TackHeaderMessage>
      <AckNackReceivedFromCMSDateTime>1900-01-01T01:01:01+01:00</AckNackReceivedFromCMSDateTime>
    </TackHeaderMessage>
    <TackPayload>
      <TackHeaderPayload>
        <TransactionId>2e105455-024b-77aa-e053-0eba1a0a9787</TransactionId>
        <LinkedContextId>EAN_ST002_2e105455-024d-77aa-e053-0eba1a0a9787</LinkedContextId>
        <LinkedCorrelationId>IMD_COR_00000000012240002150</LinkedCorrelationId>
        <LinkedTransactionId>2e105455-024f-77aa-e053-0eba1a0a9787</LinkedTransactionId>
      </TackHeaderPayload>
      <Result>
        <AckOrNack>ACK</AckOrNack>
        <HTTPCode>520</HTTPCode>
        <FaultCode>520.1</FaultCode>
        <FaultString>TEST</FaultString>
      </Result>
    </TackPayload>
  </DeliveryNotificationRecord>
</DeliveryNotificationFile>`

I want to create a record based on some attribute values from XML document.
Here is the code:

```
declare 

TYPE r_actreq_file IS RECORD ( unzip_file_name  VARCHAR2(250)
                             , sender           NUMBER(13)
                             , receiver         NUMBER(13)
                             , File_ID          VARCHAR2(40)
                             , Create_Date      DATE 
                             , Send_Date        DATE 
                             , Type             VARCHAR2(40)
                             );

gr_actreq_file  r_actreq_file;

lx_xml_file xmltype;

as_xpath_expression varchar2(25) := '/DeliveryNotificationFile';

begin
    SELECT  B_XML_FILE_CONTENT
    INTO    lx_xml_file
    FROM    INTERFACE_ENTRIES
    WHERE   seq = 1316685715;
--    dbms_output.put_line('lx_xml_file = ' || lx_xml_file.getCLOBVal());


    --retrieve the xml header data
    SELECT  header_data.sender
         ,  header_data.receiver
         ,  header_data.file_id
         ,  CAST(to_timestamp_tz(header_data.create_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM') at time zone 'Europe/Brussels' AS DATE)
         ,  CAST(to_timestamp_tz(header_data.send_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM') at time zone 'Europe/Brussels' AS DATE)
         ,  header_data.type
    INTO    gr_actreq_file.sender
         ,  gr_actreq_file.receiver
         ,  gr_actreq_file.file_id
         ,  gr_actreq_file.create_date
         ,  gr_actreq_file.send_date
         ,  gr_actreq_file.type
    FROM    XMLTABLE  (as_xpath_expression PASSING lx_xml_file
                      COLUMNS sender          NUMBER(13)    PATH  '@Sender'
                            , receiver        NUMBER(13)    PATH  '@Receiver'
                            , file_id         VARCHAR2(40)  PATH  '@FileID'
                            , create_date     DATE          PATH  '@CreateDate'
                            , send_date       DATE          PATH  '@SendDate'
                            , type            VARCHAR2(40)  PATH  '@MessageType'
                      ) header_data;

dbms_output.put_line('sender = ' || gr_actreq_file.sender || ' | receiver = ' || gr_actreq_file.receiver || ' | file_id = ' || gr_actreq_file.file_id || ' | create_date = ' || gr_actreq_file.create_date || ' | send_date = ' || gr_actreq_file.send_date || ' | type = ' || gr_actreq_file.type);
end;
```

but for unknown reason, i receive the error message:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define Create_Date and Send_Date as date in the structure and in the COLUMNS Oracle makes implicit convert to date. And because that is not the standard format for timestamp, comes error on convert. You are making the converting into the TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ. Than use strings.
Change here:

```
                         , Create_Date      VARCHAR2(50) 
                         , Send_Date        VARCHAR2(50)
```

and here:

```
XMLTABLE  (as_xpath_expression PASSING lx_xml_file
                      COLUMNS sender          NUMBER(13)    PATH  '@Sender'
                            , receiver        NUMBER(13)    PATH  '@Receiver'
                            , file_id         VARCHAR2(40)  PATH  '@FileID'
                            , create_date     VARCHAR2(50)  PATH  '@CreateDate'
                            , send_date       VARCHAR2(50)  PATH  '@SendDate'
                            , type            VARCHAR2(40)  PATH  '@MessageType'
                      ) header_data;
```

EDIT:

Actually is also possible to use TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE. Than you do not need to cast it as date (to_timezone_tz):

```
           COLUMNS sender          NUMBER(13)    PATH  '@Sender'
                    , receiver        NUMBER(13)    PATH  '@Receiver'
                    , file_id         VARCHAR2(40)  PATH  '@FileID'
                    , create_date     TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE PATH  '@CreateDate'
                    , send_date       TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE PATH  '@SendDate'
                    , type            VARCHAR2(40)  PATH  '@MessageType'
                    )
```